# Is it possible to change pandas column data type within a sklearn pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Sklearn pipeline I am using has multiple transformers but one of the initial transformers returns **numerical type** and the consecutive one takes **object type** variables.

Basically I need squeeze in a:

```
data[col] = data[col].astype(object)
```

for the required columns within the pipeline.

Is there any way to do it?

Note: I am using [*Feature-engine*](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) transformers.

Comment: From version 1.1.0 if I remember correctly Feature-engine's categorical encoders now take the parameter  ignore_format=False, which allows to apply the encoding to variables that are not of type object. So this, may simplify your pipeline, because now you don't need to re-cast the variables any more.

Comment: Also, if the transformer that is returning numerical variables is the CategoricalImputer, you can set the parameter object=True, so that it returns object directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [`sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html). A simple example would be,

```py
def to_object(x):
  return pd.DataFrame(x).astype(object)

fun_tr = FunctionTransformer(to_object)

y = fun_tr.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}))
```